# How to sync data between salesforce and external systems?

Tags: salesforce, integration, salesforce-lightning

After reading documentations and resources on salesforce website i cant find any good documentation on how to integrate salesforce with another system.

here is my question, how to integrate salesforce systems with external systems ?
for example , i have a system and based on a partnership between my organization and another organization, the other organization that use salesforce will sync data of salesforce with my external system. so how could i achieve that ?

my intent of this question is to find links to good resources that can explain or document how this could be approached. i don't expect any code here.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already seen [this one](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/integration_patterns_and_practices.pdf).

But below are some interesting primers you could refer to:

- [Salesforce Integration](https://www.slideshare.net/hoskinj/salesforce-integration-28585426)
- [Architecting Successful Integrations with Force.com](https://www.slideshare.net/Salesforce/architecting-successful-integrations-with-forcecom?next_slideshow=1)

Thanks,
Kantesh